# How do I copy one object into another and add new field to the new object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

I have an object like this:

```
{"question": "", "options" : [{"subject": "", "teacher": "", "answer": [] } 
}
```

I want to copy data from this object into this:

```
{"question": "", "options" : [{"subject": "", "teacher": "", "new":" " } 
}
```

I want to add the field "new" instead of "answer"

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 1):

Deep cloning can be achieved like this: `var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));`

The requested manipulation would be

```
var a = {"question": "", "options" : [{"subject": "", "teacher": "","answer": [] }}
var b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
delete b.options[0].answer
b.options[0].new = 'your content'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of another answer... (though I rather liked the first one from @lipp)

Here is a function that deep clones your object and swithches the **answer** key for the **new** key.

**Problem** this will substitue **any** key **answer** wherever it may find it. So that if you do this:

```
clone({"question": "", "answer" : [{"subject": "", "teacher": "", "answer": [] ] } })
```

Result is

```
{"question": "", "new" : " " }
```

---

```
var toClone = {"question": "", "options" : [{"subject": "", "teacher": "", "answer": [] ] } };

function clone(original){   
    var copy;

    if (original instanceof Array) {
        copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, limit = original.length; i < limit; ++i) {
            copy[i] = clone(original[i]);
        }
    } else  if (original instanceof Object) { 
        copy = {};
        for (var key in original) {
            if( key === "answer" ){
                copy["new"] = " "; 
            } else
                copy[copiedKey ] = clone(original[key]);
        }
    } else
        copy = original;

    return copy;
}
```